# How to limit concurrent exectuions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to download 70 images. Their complete size is around 100mb.

This is my simplified part of code

```
function downloadImage(src){
    var dst = '...';
    request(src).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst));
    return dst;
}

arrayOf70.forEach(function(e){
    var thing = new Thing({
        // ...
        image: downloadImage(url)
    });
    thing.save();
}
```

The problem is there are too much concurrent downloads. Okay first step: Pass a huge timeout to request.

```
request({url: src, timeout: 120000000}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst));
```

Well, that didn't worked well since it exceeds the OS TCP timeout. At least I think that's the problem. Anyway I'm getting timed out connections

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
```

So. What is the way to go to limit the amount of concurrent downloads?

Comment: Why not use setInterval() to make the requests some milliseconds after each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts are not an ideal solution. What you really need is the ability to wait for a download to finish and afterwards immediately start a new download. And that a specific number of times in parallel.
You could do that by using a callback.

```
function downloadImage(src, callback){
  var dst = '...';
  http.get(src, function(res) {
    res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst))
      .on("finish", function() {
        callback(dst);
    });
  });
}    
function downloadAllImages(array) {
  var idx = 0;

  function downloadLoop() {
    if(idx >= array.length) return;
    downloadImage(array[idx++], function(dst) {
      var thing = new Thing({
          // ...
          image: dst
      });
      thing.save();
      downloadLoop();
    });
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) downloadLoop(); //start 5 concurrent download "loops"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with setInterval:

```
var array_length = arrayOf70.length;
var i = 0;

var request_interval = setInterval(makeRequest, 100);

function makeRequest()
   if(i<array_length){
      var thing = new Thing({
         // ...
         image: downloadImage(url)
      });
      thing.save();
      i++;
   }else{
      clearInterval(request_interval);
   }
},100);
```